# adMob don't show any ads on new project (new bundle id)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I tested my AdMob app ID on another project (different bundle ID) and it worked out well. I changed the current bundle ID to another old project (which has AdMob and ads that work fine) and Ads worked fine. So the problem is in the bundle ID. How can we resolve this issue?

Note that I performed all steps for iOS 14 in the AdMob documentation -> [Prepare for iOS 14+](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14)

**Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.64.0 , and iOS 14**

Comment: Have you registered both apps on AdMob?

Comment: you mean bundle Id needs to registration on admob ? 
if yes , can you show me how can I do that

Comment: I used AdMob a long time ago. however you need to register your apps before you can display ads in them

Comment: ok thank you , I think that is the problem

Comment: It's a pleasure. However remember to only use the test ads when you're on simulator or they could ban you for life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a new app on your Google AdMob account before you can display ads on it.
[Here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zC075pcM7rc)